# Thousands separator and decimal places formatting with TEXT in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I use TEXT in excel to format a string to get a `,` thousand separator and 2 decimal places

I tried `=("GBP "&TEXT(A1,"###,#.##")` but I get `GBP 1,234.5` without the last `0`

I also tried `=("GBP "&TEXT(A1,"###,#.00")` and when A1 = `0`, I get `GBP .00` (my current workaround is to say when A1 is `0`, return `""`, but I'd like to be able to do this without that condition)

Desired:

When A1 is `0`, I want to get `GBP 0.00`

When its `1,234.50`, I want to get `GBP 1,234.50`

Comment: What do you want it to show when A1 is empty or zero? If 0.00 then use this format string: "#,##0.00"

Comment: You can set a custom format for the cell equal to "GBP" #,##0.00. I think that is a cleaner approach. Take a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4

Comment: @jkpieterse - Thanks, can you add this so I can mark it as answer

Comment: @Johan Thanks GBP is a variable that could change, it coukd be PKR depeninf on the formular etc, hence not using custom formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number format used in either a cell's [number format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-format-codes-5026BBD6-04BC-48CD-BF33-80F18B4EAE68) or in a [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945) can have up to four different styles; positive, negative, zero and text. These are separated by semi-colons. You can provide a blank result for any of the types by supplying nothing for that section.

```
=TEXT(A3, "\G\P\D #,##0.00;;;")
```

[image: number_codes]